# Control camel routes execution based on the running status of other camel routes

Tags: apache-camel

Is there any way that I can run a camel route based on the running status of a different camel route?

**Route-1** : rest --> seda:queue --> direct:camelrouteTwo --> direct:camelrouteOne

direct:camelrouteTwo should call direct:camelrouteOne only when direct:camelrouteOne is not in a running state so that it will not collide with Route-2. I just want to keep only one instance of direct:camelrouteOne must be running always.

**Route-2** : timer --> direct:camelrouteOne

any possible ways, plsss ??